# Wordpress update_user_metadata is not giving $prev_value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to see if a user's field value was changed, if it was changed i need to run some code. So, the best way i found to do this was use this filter hook.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/update_(meta_type)_metadata

However, for some reason i am getting null if i try to output my $prev_value and my field was not blank before. Why is that?

```
function myplugin_init() {
    add_filter( 'update_user_metadata', 'myplugin_update_foo', 10, 5 );
}

function myplugin_update_foo( $null, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ) {

    if ( 'last_name' == $meta_key ) {
    echo "<h1>Prev: ". $prev_value ."</h1>";
    echo "<h1>New: ". $meta_value ."</h1>";
  }

    return null; // this means: go on with the normal execution in meta.php

}

add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_init' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. If you call `update_user_meta`, you need to add a fourth argument with the previous value. e.g.:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_field', 'new_value', get_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_field', true ) );
```

Only then you will have access to the `prev_value` in the `update_user_metadata` filter & action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the WordPress action `update_user_metadata` only has four parameters.

You are using `$prev_value` as a fifth parameter so it will always be `null`.

```
<?php
add_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'my_update_user_meta', 10, 4 );

function my_update_user_meta($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
    //do stuff
} ?>
```

Reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_(meta_type)_meta

Comment: You are looking and the wrong action, click my link.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Did you try to dump `$_GET` or `$_POST` to see if the data is coming in?

Comment: Yes i did, data is coming in fine.